# jquery - add to array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why this not working?

```
var inputs = new Array();
$("input").each(function(){
    input = $(this).val();
})

console.log(input);
```

how to correctly use arrays in jQuery? Like as PHP?

Comment: Arrays are part of native JavaScript, there's no special jQuery syntax for them. However, your code shows a total lack of understanding of basic programming concepts, so I'd suggest you go back and cover those.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: the array needs an index . eg `input[0] = $(this).val();`

Comment: @AnthonyGrist he is asking a question because he doesn't know to do it.

Comment: @Raminson - agreed, that comment was unnecessarily hostile.

Comment: I think its a fair comment ... pointing the user in the right direction

Comment: @man - "in the right direction"?  How is `"go back and cover basic programming concepts"` pointing in any direction?  It is saying go learn... The fact that the comment is 100% correct is besides the point... But it still is not very helpful...  **It is an RTFM if I ever did see one...**

Comment: @Raminson He's asking a question that he shouldn't need to ask if he'd covered the basic concepts of programming in JavaScript. There are plenty of well-written guides covering them to be found in less than a minute on Google. There's no research effort on his part (criteria for downvoting) and the question isn't going to be useful to anybody else (criteria for closing as too localized).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist You are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume what you are trying to do is get an array of the values of all the  `<input>` elements on your page.  What you'll need to do is iterate over all the elements using the `.each()` function and append each value to your `inputs` array.

Try this -

```
 var inputs = new Array();
  $("input").each(function(){
      inputs.push($(this).val());
  })

  console.log(inputs);
```

You need to use the `push()` function to add an element to an array.

## [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HTztq/)

---

References -

- [Array push method on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

---

As a final note, here is a shorthand way to define a new array -

```
var inputs = [];
```

That line is functionally identical to -

```
var inputs = new Array();
```

Comment: Technically `input = $(this).val();` will define the variable on the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```
var inputs = new Array();
$("input").each(function(){
   inputs.push($(this).val());
})
```

Also note the variable differences .. `input != inputs`

Comment: But I think this is more constructive. +1